# `\/` italics correction within \textit{} produces unwanted extra space

Tags: italic, italic-correction

My knowledge of LaTeX is not very much up to date, but I've learned to use italics correction (`\/`) whenever you do not want ligatures to be used, like for `\textit{Farbauf\/lösung}` (for non-Germans: The word means "color resolution", and you would hyphenate between "f" and "l", so the ligature seems bad).
When rendering with pdflatex I get something like this:

[image: Rendering of "Farbauflösung"]

However when I use `\section{Auf\/lösungsvermögen}`, the I don't see that effect.

I read in [some common (la)tex errors](https://economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/latex/LTXERR.HTM) that italics correction is not needed within `\texit` in most cases, but still is in some cases.
That isn't really helpful to me, so what's going on and what to do?

Comment: If you use `babel`, the correct way should be `Farbauf"|lösung`

Comment: You're fast ;-) Actually I'm using `\usepackage[german]{babel}`, so what does that `"|` mean?

Comment: If you (a) don't want to perform ligature suppression manually and (b) are able to use LuaLaTeX, you may want to look into using the `selnolig` package, which performs suppression of selected ligatures for german and english documents. E.g., try running `\documentclass[ngerman]{article} \usepackage{fontspec,babel,selnolig} \begin{document} \itshape Farbauflösung \end{document}` under LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the description of the shorthands available with `babel-german`. Several of them are no longer really needed with UTF-8 input.

In your case, to separate word fragments at a morpheme boundary, the construct to use is `"|`. It also adds a possible hyphenation point, according to the rules of German.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\begin{document}

\textit{Farbauf"|lösung}

\end{document}
```

Note also that `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` does some adjustments to conform to Neue Rechtschreibung. Pick the option that best suits you.

[image: Output using \textit{Farbauf"|lösung}]

### Note:

Remember to quote `"` and `|` when using it for an `\index` entry (like `\index{Farbauf'"'|lösung}` when using `quote '\''`).

Comment: Should I replace even those `\/` outside of `\textit`s? OK, it works fine, but when also adding it to the index, I get a somewhat funny `auf" . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . łösung` for `\index{Farb-!auf"|lösung}` (before I just had had `\index{Farb-!auflösung}`). Suggestions?

Comment: @U.Windl That's a different question altogether.

Comment: @U.Windl `"` and `|` are special characters for MakeIndex and they should be quoted with `"`: `\index{Farb-!auf"""|lösung}`